# Is there a way to run a python code directly from Excel?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm looking for a way to run a python code directly from Excel.

**My goal**:
The code takes 5 separate csv files as input, processes the data and then outputs a single csv file.
I want to know if it's possible to run this code directly from the main input file.

I find it much easier to code in python than in VBA, so if there's a add-in, library or some module I can use to run this code, please let me know.

I've seen some people using xlwings or running a shell object to call a python function but since my code has a bunch of UDFs that returns multiple values and involves reading many csv files I don't think it'll work. (I've read that shell objects can't deal with functions that return values)

Any help is appreciated!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i've used for many years another good alternative [pyxll](https://www.pyxll.com/) it can handle ranges ov values (not only scalar) that are binded automatically to numpy od pandas. you can see it in action [here](https://www.pyxll.com/docs/examples/pandastypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlwings for UDFs. Follow this documentation: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#workbook-directory-config-config-file

This document also has step by spet guide:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-supercharge-excel-with-python-726b0f8e22c2